# How to proceed with Thévenin

Tags: thevenin, homework, network, norton

> Find the short circuit current with respect to A and B.

When applying Thévenin's theorem to find I<sub>sc</sub> the 4 Ω resistor becomes 0. How to proceed further?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the short circuit current is clearly zero.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with dependent sources you find \$R_\mathrm{TH}\$ by finding the **open circuit voltage** \$V_\mathrm{openAB}\$ (remove the load resistor) using nodal analysis and the **short circuit current** \$I_\mathrm{shortAB}\$ (short A with B) using mesh analysis then divide $$ \frac{V_\mathrm{openAB}}{I_\mathrm{shortAB}}$$